# Clone a div depending of the number submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I would like to know how to clone my div depending of the number submitted by the user. If he enter 3 and press submit this will clone 3 div, if 42 ---> 42 div cloned and so on. Someone can help ?

For now i just have a button that clone my div each time i press it.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function colorDiv() {
     var selection = document.getElementById('color').value;
     var div = document.getElementById('change');
     
    
    
    
     switch (selection) {
      case "1":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
      break;
      case "2":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;
      case "3":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
      case "4":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
      case "5":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
     }
    }
    
    function multi() {
    
     var item = document.getElementById("change");
     var ligne = document.getElementById("br");
     var dupli = item.cloneNode(true);
     var dupliLig = ligne.cloneNode(true);
     document.body.appendChild(dupli);
     document.body.appendChild(dupliLig);
    }
```

```html
<div id="change" style="height:200px; width:200px"></div>
    <br id="br">
    <select id="color" onchange="colorDiv()">
     <option value=1>Grey</option>
     <option value=2>Yellow</option>
     <option value=3>Blue</option>
     <option value=4>Red</option>
     <option value=5>Green</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="text" name="">
    <input type="submit" onclick= "multi()" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `numer` input to get the count. You can add `max` and `min` to restrict the count. Get the value of this on clicking submit. Use this `count` to iterate your cloning that much times using a simple `for` loop.

Also try to use a `class` instead of `id` for `change` as `id` need to be unique. When cloning you end up having different elements with same id, which is invalid HTML.

```js
function colorDiv() {
  var selection = document.getElementById('color').value;
  var div = document.getElementById('change');
  switch (selection) {
    case "1":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
      break;
    case "2":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;
    case "3":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
    case "4":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
    case "5":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
  }
}

function multi() {
  var item = document.getElementById("change");
  var count = +document.getElementById("count").value;
  var ligne = document.getElementById("br");
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var dupli = item.cloneNode(true);
    var dupliLig = ligne.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(dupli);
    document.body.appendChild(dupliLig);
  }
}

window.onload = colorDiv;
```

```html
<div id="change" style="height:200px; width:200px"></div>
<br id="br">
<select id="color" onchange="colorDiv()">
     <option value=1>Grey</option>
     <option value=2>Yellow</option>
     <option value=3>Blue</option>
     <option value=4>Red</option>
     <option value=5>Green</option>
    </select>

<input type="number" id="count" min="1" max="100" value="1" />
<input type="submit" onclick="multi()">
```

Comment: Perfect ! Was thinking about for loop but not like that :) ty

Answer (score 0):

In your multi() function you need to add a For statement asSiam is saying.

Example:

```
function multi() {
var times = parseInt($("input[type='text']").val());
for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    var item = document.getElementById("change");
    var ligne = document.getElementById("br");
    var dupli = item.cloneNode(true);
    var dupliLig = ligne.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(dupli);
    document.body.appendChild(dupliLig);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="" id="times">
```

Get the number from input tag and loop cloning operation that many times.

```
function multi() {
    var times = parseInt(document.getElementById("times").value);
    for(i=0;i<times;i++){
        var item = document.getElementById("change");
        var ligne = document.getElementById("br");
        var dupli = item.cloneNode(true);
        var dupliLig = ligne.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(dupli);
        document.body.appendChild(dupliLig);
      }
    }
```

```js
function colorDiv() {
     var selection = document.getElementById('color').value;
     var div = document.getElementById('change');
     
    
    
    
     switch (selection) {
      case "1":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
      break;
      case "2":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;
      case "3":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
      case "4":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
      case "5":
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
     }
    }
    
    function multi() {
    var times = parseInt(document.getElementById("times").value);
    for(i=0;i<times;i++){
     var item = document.getElementById("change");
     var ligne = document.getElementById("br");
     var dupli = item.cloneNode(true);
     var dupliLig = ligne.cloneNode(true);
     document.body.appendChild(dupli);
     document.body.appendChild(dupliLig);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="change" style="height:200px; width:200px"></div>
    <br id="br">
    <select id="color" onchange="colorDiv()">
     <option value=1>Grey</option>
     <option value=2>Yellow</option>
     <option value=3>Blue</option>
     <option value=4>Red</option>
     <option value=5>Green</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="text" name="" id="times">
    <input type="submit" onclick= "multi()" >
```